# ORA-01194: file needs one more recovery to be consistent & ORA-01110:data file : 'C:\APP\KUNLE\ORADATA\ORCL\SYSTEM01.DBF'

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

```
ORA-01194: file needs one more recovery to be consistent & ORA-01110:data file : 'C:\APP\KUNLE\ORADATA\ORCL\SYSTEM01.DBF'
```

please how do I make the file recovery to be consistent?

Comment: Use existing backups to recover.

Comment: Show the statement you used. But, as @JSapkota wrote, and as the message indicates, you need to recover your file from backup. Perhaps you just restored the file?